# scrapy stop storing pages with http error, How to?

Tags: scrapy

i use cache in Scrapy. First i collect all pages to cache, then start collect data.
but sometimes on weak sites i see it:

```
 DEBUG: Crawled (504)  < url.....>   ['cached']
```

why page with error saved to cache?
how to disable it?

TEST:

```
  <?php
    http_response_code (504);
  ?>
```

run spider with cache.
 then
 change page to

```
  <?php
    echo 1;
  ?>
```

run spider again and get:

```
   DEBUG: Crawled (504)  < url.....>   ['cached']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default HTTP cache policy is [`DummyPolicy`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?#dummy-policy-default). As the name implies, it's pretty basic:

> The Dummy policy is useful for testing spiders faster (without having
>   to wait for downloads every time) and for trying your spider offline,
>   when an Internet connection is not available. The goal is to be able
>   to “replay” a spider run exactly as it ran before.

You have the option to set some HTTP codes that you do not want to cache with the [`HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?#httpcache-ignore-http-codes) setting.

Another option is to use a [(nearly) RFC2616-compliant policy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?#rfc2616-policy):

```
HTTPCACHE_POLICY = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.RFC2616Policy'
```